# Put out unicode symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

Want to type symbol(â) in unicode in Visual Studio C++ program. Try this:

```
cout << "Let \u00E2";
```

but puts out some kind of cyrillic letter (probably because Windows OS is Russian?)
Code page Visual C++ using seems to be 65001 (which is UTF-8), but not sure how can I check this.

Comment: You should use L prefix for Unicode string literals

Comment: If you want to output `UTF-8` then you need to convert `"â"` to `UTF-8` which is `"\xC3\xA2"` according to http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: @Asesh L prefix only for wchar_t and wcout no?

Comment: `cout` uses ANSI codepage by default. Use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); wcout << L"Let \u00E2";`. Make sure you have font for console that can display the character. Also see linked question.